# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not calling on submit event

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, gps

I am working with Cordova (latest version), jQuery Mobile (latest version) project where I need to call the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function on form submit event.

It's working perfectly on deviceready event although it isn't called when I press submit on form.

Here is my code below in body section:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQM.js"></script>//JQuery mobile library
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq_validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gps_gcm.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);//This working perfactly
    function onDeviceReady() {          
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1);//callback function included in "js/gps_gcm.js" file
    }

    $("#gps_loc").click(function() {
        alert("test gps");//I got this alert
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1);//**callback function included in "js/gps_gcm.js" file but seems like this function is not calling?**
        alert("test gps end");//I also got this alert
    });

    $('#form1').validate({// using jquery library for validation form "js/jq_validate.js" included above
        rules: {
            f_name: {
                required: true
            },
            mob_no: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            merchant_name: {
                //required: true,
                number: true
            }        
        },
        messages: {
            f_name: {
                required: "Please enter your first name."
            },
            mob_no: {
                required: "Please enter your last name."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email."
            },
            merchant_name: {
              //  required: "Please enter your email."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var category_val="";
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){

              category_val += $(this).val()+",";
              //alert(category_val);
            });
            var categoryies = category_val.slice(0,-1);
            //start all function calling one by one 
            alert(categoryies);//I got this alert
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1);//**callback function included in "js/gps_gcm.js" file but seems like this function is not calling?**
            alert("end navigation");//I also got this alert


            return false;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Please advise and feel free to ask for more information

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance

Sincerly,
-Niks

Comment: Could you also include your callbacks?

Comment: wrap your code in `pagecreate`.

Comment: @meskobalazs yes i included in "js/gps_gcm.js"

Comment: jQuery(document).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {   $("#gps_loc").click(function() {
        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1);
       
    })});  @Omar like this?

Comment: yes, `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () { your code here });`

Comment: by including, I meant writing it into the question

Comment: @Omar Thanks it works but sometimes this function hangs up neither calling error callback nor executing further code.By the the way thank for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation is failing because getCurrentPosition is asynchronous and you are expecting it to be synchronous. You can solve this problem by keeping track of the position of the device and use this in the form submit using `navigator.geolocator.watchPosition`.

Just be sure to only call this after `deviceready` to avoid constant permissions popups

Here is MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition

Alternatively, you could put your submit code inside the callback that you give to getCurrentPosition, but that means that you will have to do the form POST yourself using jQuery.post or something similar. Tracking the position is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I don't want to keep track of position of the device but i want to store latitude longitude when user submits form into the database.So i want current location using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1) on form submit success callback but it can't happen,Any suggestions?

Comment: Added some more alternatives